# Need to create parametric equation for epitrochoid evolute

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am posting this because this equation is too complicated for me to figure out and I looked online finding no solution.

Basically I have a parametric equation for points $(x, y)$ which defines an [epitrochoid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Epitrochoid.html). I also know the equation to find the evolute, but it's not in parametric form. The dirty form of the equation for the evolute is found in [the "Evolute" entry on Xahlee.info](http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/Evolute_dir/evolute.html).

I have even provided a graph showing the epitrochoid (parametric formula) and its evolute (non-parametric formula) using the equations:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/itxanasb5v

What I desperately need is the parametric form of the equation. It's going to be huge formula. The formula of graph I need is in red.

I don't remember calculus, but I know I'm going to need first and second derivatives.

Thanks in advance.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Do you mean "*parametric* equation"?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question to say "parametric"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Desmos project, the epitrochoid is parameterized by $(f(t),g(t))$, where
$$\begin{align}
f(t) &= bc\cos t - h \cos ct \\
g(t) &= bc\sin t - h \sin ct 
\end{align} \tag1$$
and I'm defining $c:=(a+b)/b$ to save myself some typing.

Again from your project, the evolute can be written as
$$\left(f-g' k,\,g + f' k\right) \qquad\text{where}\qquad k = \frac{f'^{\,2}+g'^{\,2}}{f'g''-f''g'} \tag2$$
Calculating the derivatives is straightforward:
$$\begin{align}
f'(t) &= -bc\sin t\,+hc\sin ct \\
f''(t) &= -bc\cos t+hc^2\cos ct \\[6pt]
g'(t) &= \phantom{-}bc\cos t-hc\cos ct \\
g''(t) &= -bc\sin t\,+hc^2\sin ct
\end{align} \tag3$$
Substituting into $(2)$ is tedious, but not terrible (especially with a computer algebra system). We get
$$k = \frac{h^2+b^2 - 2 hb \cos dt}{bp+hcq} \tag4$$
$$d:=c-1=\frac{a}{b} \qquad\qquad p:= b-h\cos dt \qquad\qquad q := h-b\cos dt$$
and, with a bit of simplifying,
$$(f-g'k, g+f'k ) = \left(
\frac{a h (p \cos ct + c q \cos t)}{b p + h c q}, 
\frac{a h (p \sin ct + c q \sin t)}{b p + h c q}\right) \tag5$$

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I want to express my deep appreciation for this answer. Probably the best answer I've ever gotten. It works, and I've updated the Desmos project to show the updated parametric equation. Thanks again so much!

Comment: Also, incase anyone else is looking, the evolute of the HYPOtrochoid is Blue's answer, but make all the + signs - signs leaving the y numerator + sign. Posting my Desmos, ORANGE graph is Blue's answer, and PURPLE graph is just another way of writing it. Epitrochoid: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wyoy7hl3xv and Hypotrochoid: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xxnmhepjfx